# PHP: Basic loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I recently started to try to teach myself PHP. I've only taken a beginner class in C before, so this is a little new to me.

I was fiddling around with some basic code just to practice:

```
<?php

$num = 0;

while ($num < 5)
{
    if ($num == 1)
    {
        echo 'There is' . $num . ' monkey.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'There are ' . $num . ' monkeys.';
        $num++;
    }
}

?>
```

However, it won't run and Chrome asks me if I would like to kill the page.
Did I create an infinite loop somehow without realizing it?

Thank you!

Comment: It will go infinite when `num == 1`, as you aren't incrementing num in that if.

Comment: When num is 1, you don't increment again, so it never becomes 2: put your increment __outside__ of the if/else

Comment: First loop: `$num == 0`. Second loop: `$num == 1` -> `$num` is never updated again -> infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did create an infinite loop; you forgot to include `$num++` in the original `if` statement (it's only in the `else`, so the execution gets stuck at `1`).

This is a better way:

```
<?php

$num = 0;

while ($num < 5)
{
    if ($num == 1)
    {
        echo 'There is' . $num . ' monkey.';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'There are ' . $num . ' monkeys.';
    }
    $num++;//moved outside the if statement
}
```

?>